# Scheduled auto responder to emails from domain

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using the script below to schedule out of office responses, but would like it only to apply to emails received from a specific domain.

Can someone please help how I tweak this script?

```
function autoReply() {
  var interval = 5;    //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  var hour = date.getHours();
  if ([5,6].indexOf(day) > -1 || (day == 0 && hour < 7) || (day == 4 && hour >= 16)) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      threads[i].reply("Out of office hours. Your email will not read until Sunday morning.");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak the Gmail search query to include the from: search operator. As the is:inbox should be in:inbox.

```
var threads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox from:example.com after:' + timeFrom);
```

If you run the script via trigger, there's a possibility that the same emails is replied multiple times. Therefore you can consider using thread.moveToArchive() to remove the message from inbox after it has been responded.